# Stop autocomplete of /* comments in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm still somewhat of a newbie with VS, but I like many of the features that I didn't have with my old love, Textpad.

However, when I open multi-line comments with /*, it automatically fills the trailing */.

[image]

How do I go about stopping this particular auto-complete?

Comment: Hey @Scott there is one downside of the solution, I'm sure you've also discovered it... When typing `/*` then everything below which is folded, becomes unfolded. What a pain! I often find myself typing `*/` and then `/*` to avoid that problem, but often forget. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: What do you mean by 'folded'?

Comment: "folded" as in the code is collapsed, you need to use + and - to fold/unfold the code blocks.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I never use that. I just tried to recreate your problem, and was all OK for me.

Comment: Select the lines you want to comment out, or have the cursor on the single line, then press `Ctrl+/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for workaround posted [at the repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1966).

Comment: Awesome. I found my language configuration here C:\Users\wesleys\.vscode\extensions\xyz.plsql-language-1.8.1\syntaxes and removed auto-closing pair for comments. I think brackets will follow soon after.

Comment: Yeah works for me too. Remember to accept, unless you want to wait for an "official" fix, but none is coming anytime soon I'm afraid.

Comment: what's to fix? The person who authored the relevant language syntax files obviously preferred such optional behaviours.

Comment: My PL/SQL extension was updated, and my updated language file was overwritten. Sigh.

Comment: hate when that happens :(

Comment: Thank you for the link to the work-around, but it would be better to include information from the relevant comment.

Answer (score 4):

This should be supported with the upcoming VSCode 1.83 (Sept. 2023), and already available today (Sept. 2023) with [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

See [`microsoft/vscode` issue 1966](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1966) "Proposal: Ability not to auto-close comments", resolved with [PR 192335](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/192335).

You have the new option `autoClosingComments`:

- `autoClosingComments`: Controls whether the editor should automatically close comments after the user adds an opening comment: values '`always`', '`languageDefined`', '`beforeWhitespace`', or '`never`'

  - `editor.autoClosingComments.languageDefined`: Use language configurations to determine when to autoclose comments.
  - `editor.autoClosingComments.beforeWhitespace`: Autoclose comments only when the cursor is to the left of whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Option in Visual Studio to toggle "Automatic brace completion".
From the Tools menu, select Options.
From the options tree, expand Text Editor, and All Languages.
Select General, and then uncheck the "Automatic brace completion" checkbox.
Press Save.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPP93.png)

Comment: This is a Visual Studio Code question, not Visual Studio.

Comment: Irrelevant to VSCode, and irrelevant to the question - this is about closing comments, not braces.  Disabling `autoClosingComments` works asper the other answer.